# 2012 T-SQL: Parse Field from table

Tags: t-sql

I have the following rows into a table:

```
 Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ reimbur.docx  
 Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ testing.docx  
 Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ updates.txt                
 Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ today.docx    
 Import Development \ chiro.docx                                    
 Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ kempt.docx    
 Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ quater.xls    
 Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ elect.docx
```

I need to extract the string before the last backslash; my results should be the text listed in red in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability I have created a variable so you can see whats going on. TSQL has no concept of LastIndexOf such as in C#. So you have to reverse the string then you can do it. Here it is

```
 declare @myString varchar(max) = 'Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ reimbur.docx'
 select substring((@myString), 1, len(@myString) - charindex('\', reverse (@myString)))
```

Comment: This one is working perfect with the variable. When I try to run from the table using: **select substring([path], 1, len([path]) - charindex('\', reverse ([path]))) from table** , i get the error: Invalid length passed to substring function. Any idea?

Comment: @Joe, maybe the value in the table doesn't have the ``\`` character at all.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: I can confirm that the table has this value: **Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ reimbur.docx     **

Comment: I get the error "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function." as i said; if I look at the Results table, this is what I have: Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny . It looks like this portion  "Asti \ reimbur.docx " does not get parsed properly..

Comment: Hi Joe, there is probably some strange data in one of the rows. One trick is to look at 1/2 the data then 1/2 again etc until you find the offending row. Then send me that row and I can work out a case statement that will get around the problem. Alternatively dump the whole table out and I can have a look at it.

Comment: @cameront: You are correct, there were trailing spaces at the end of the row and that was the reason for the error. Vladimir helped me with this issue (removed the trailing spaces using RTRIM), thanks to both of you guys.